# Xdebug silently catches connections with no reason

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

The application runs on docker containers: nginx and php-fpm. Xdebug is configured with PhpStorm. The app was working correctly until suddenly Xdebug started to catch all connections even when I didn't enable debugging. I didn't even change anything in configuration - it just started to do this (a bit magic but of course there should be something).

Why it's Xdebug: if I remove the Xdebug settings from Dockerfile, everything starts working. Also, requests hang like it happens when I debug them, i.e. they die after a few minutes waiting with the `504 Gateway Time-out` error.

PhpStorm doesn't start a debug session, so it happens silently. Closing PhpStorm doesn't help. Restart of containers, the docker daemon itself and even OS don't help as well.  Nothing changes in different browsers.

`php-fpm/Dockerfile`:

```docker
FROM php:7.3.18-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

#...there are more lines, but even when I remove them, the issue remains

#When I comment this line and do `docker-compose build && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`, 
# the app returns to life.
COPY xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

`php-fpm/xdebug.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off
xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/vhost.conf.template:/tmp/vhost.conf.template
      - ./docker/nginx/logs:/logs
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=app.local
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

`nginx/vhost.conf`:

```nginx
server {
    charset              utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    listen               80;

    server_name app.local;
    root        /app/public;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /logs/nginx.app.access.log;
    error_log   /logs/nginx.app.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }

    location ~* "/\." {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }
}
```

It's Docker Desktop 2.5.0 on MacOS 10.14.6.

What could it be?

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log and see what it will say there. 2) Better show your all Xdebug settings (actual settings). Show whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured in the same way as you run it (CLI or a web page). On Linux/Mac it's common to have separate php.ini for CLI and web server. Maybe you have set a connection delay to a very long value (0.2sec is the default). 3) What service do you have on that TCP 10000? Inside your Docker as well as (most importantly) on your host OS (Mac). Use `lsof` for that, e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: 3) Do you actually need `xdebug.remote_autostart=true` option? It tells Xdebug to try to debug every single script. Have you tried using Xdebug browser extension/bookmarklet instead to control what page to debug? P.S. `xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost` You can use `host.docker.internal` instead for quite a while now (also works on Windows .. and with small changes on Linux as well)...

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your help, your guess about TCP 10000 was the answer. It turned out I had another application on that port that caught all the requests before Xdebug.
And thanks for the tips about the settings, I will consider changing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why it's Xdebug: if I remove the Xdebug settings from Dockerfile, everything starts working. Also, requests hang like it happens when I debug them, i.e. they die after a few minutes waiting with the `504 Gateway Time-out` error.

Enable Xdebug log to confirm that the debug session is established and check what communication is going on there (if any). This should give you some clues on what that might be.

Anyway, it looks like you have some service on that TCP 10000 port already (on your host OS (Mac)) that prevents PhpStorm from listening there (IDE can detect already occupied port on Windows and Linux but not on Mac -- [WI-29443](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29443)).

Use something like `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` and check what that service might be. Then either shutdown that app or use another port (either for that app or for your Xdebug communications).

Comment: Its easy to say `Enable Xdebug log`. How to do that? Tried `xdebug.remote_log="/home/app/api/xdebug.log"` and `xdebug.log="/home/app/api/xdebug.log"`, not working. Nothing is filled in that file when the error occurs. Having xdebug 3.1.4.

Comment: @fabpico Yes, you need to configure `xdebug.log` property -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log . Do not forget to restart your webserver so that PHP reads the new parameters. Then check the `xdebug_info()` output (captured in the same way you are trying to debug) and see if this option has the expected value. With default `xdebug.log_level = 7` it should write the connection attempts info (if it tries to connect to anywhere ofc). You can set `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` to tell Xdebug to try to debug every single request without looking for `debug me` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on `php:8.1.25-fpm-alpine` & `xdebug-3.1.4`.

Changing `xdebug.client_port` to 9999 did not fix it.

**Fixed with a PC restart**.